# Card Data/fetcher/ previewer API configuration for a php website on Magic the Gathering

Tags: php, mysql, api

I would define myself as a junior PHP developer (as have written small  scripts occasionally). A week ago I started a new project to make a website for magic the gathering (card game) where users write and publish their articles on the game or tournaments. 
Normally it wouldn't be a problem because if there is any external source, it could by hyperlinked and the problem is solved. 
But in this case in articles users have to discuss about MTG cards, upload decklists and stuff like that and can't put hyperlinks for these things and neither create a database for all cards as only 3 months new cards are published with new set release.

What I am looking for is a 3rd party code integration into my project where user typing a string such as "[card_data]NAME OF CARD[card_data]" have a card preview by clicking on it.
There are several websites like:
https://www.mtggoldfish.com/articles/instant-deck-tech-five-color-birds-modern 
https://www.channelfireball.com/all-strategy/articles/
and several other website.

I couldn't try anything because I don't know the procedure to call an API in php script, tutorials on youtube, or w3schools are very simple and often they are about facebook and google apis .

There are websites that have APi available for mtg cards data such as https://docs.magicthegathering.io/
https://scryfall.com/docs/api
https://www.echomtg.com/api/

But I am missing the part of integration them in my website.

I would like to have something like in this example where "Wasteland" is a card and by hovering on it or clicking on it there should be a card preview:
Of course, the easiest way to make **Wasteland** useless is never to play any land at all

Comment: I'd recommend dropping w3schools as a learning resource, it's terribly vague and filled with bad practices - especially the PHP section

Comment: completely agree with you. Normally I use SO where a lot genius and good people give a lot important info, and then try them by myself. It is my 1st time with a question on SO as I couldn't find anything regarding my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really easy and simple solution to the problem above. I'll use tooltips of https://deckbox.org/help/tooltips